# how to connect ionic4 app to php sever on local machine

Tags: php, ionic4

where the code "mysqli.connect" which is used to connect an application to localhost should be written in ionic 4 application?
I am trying to connect a ionic sample application to localhost/phpmyadmin database so plz someone help me to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check sources like https://ionicframework.com/blog/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/ and http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic/ ? What errors did you get?

Comment: you can use your local ip-address to connect ionic app with php.
Remember ionic is used for frontend and you need an php api to connect your app.

Comment: kk i will build php api